# How to draw layout having lines between fields using javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, layout, lines

[image: I need layout like this]

Is there any way in draw layouts like this in javascript dynamically.This layout should be interactive also, like I click on the line and something happens. Is there any library that can help me.

I tried canvas but not really getting the functionality as i needed.

Comment: Try to use jQuery

Comment: Sure. Canvas can do that (eg, GoJS). SVG can do that (eg, D3). Even html draggable divs using transforms can do that (D.I.Y.)